# Can't access an option element of a select tag in Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium

I am having trouble selecting an option in a dropdown. I am using Selenium in Python.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<select class="hm-input hm-dropdown" type="text" id="HME-10- 
widget_calendar_1" style="height: 2.2em; width: 233px; font- 
family: arial; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; font-size: 11px; 
display: none;" data-role="dropdownlist"\>

<option value=""\>\</option\>

<option value="0"\>Week To Date\</option\>

<option value="1"\>Month To Date\</option\>

<option value="2"\>Quarter To Date\</option\>

<option value="3"\>Year To Date\</option\>

<option value="4"\>X To Date\</option\>

<option value="5" selected="selected"\>Last Week\</option\>

<option value="6"\>Last Month\</option\>

<option value="7"\>Last Quarter\</option\>

<option value="8"\>Last Year\</option\>

<option value="9"\>Last 4 Weeks\</option\>

<option value="10"\>Last 13 Weeks\</option\>

<option value="11"\>Last 26 Weeks\</option\>

<option value="12"\>Last 52 Weeks\</option\>

<option value="13"\>Rolling Days\</option\>

<option value="14"\>Rolling Weeks\</option\>

</select\>
```

I am trying to select the option with value 12 labeled Last 52 Weeks.

Here is the code I am trying, but having no luck with. Any help is appreciated.

```
sel52 = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 
30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//\*\. 
[@id="HME-10-widget_calendar_1"\]'))))

sel52.select_by_value('12')
```

I am getting A timeout exception using this code.

Comment: _but having no luck with_ This doesn't tell us much.  If you're getting an error, post it.

Comment: If you know the element id, why are you bothering to use xpath at all?  Finding an element by its id is much easier.

Comment: The backslashes in the xpath may be the problem.  This isn't a regex, so you shouldn't need backslashes at all...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Change your locator to `(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="HME-10-widget_calendar_1"]')` or even better to `(By.ID, 'HME-10-widget_calendar_1')`